# UIStepper horizontal position in StoryBoard correct, but not in the running App

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a problem with the UIStepper and XCode. I am coding for iOS 5.
In storyboard the stepper has the correct position, but later in the App its position is higher than it should be. because above the Stepper there's a button the stepper now is on the top of that button.
I tested the App with Simulator and iPhone, both the same issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I solved it. The autosizing attribute for that item was wrong.